# Should each method be its own answer?

Tags: discussion

There are a good number of questions on this site that have answers which include multiple methods to solve the problem. Should these individual method be each in their own answer? The benefits of this system are:

- When a new users comes along in the future and sees an answer with multiple method he might not know which one is better, why he should chose one over the other.
- Individual method have their own votes, it becomes very clear which is best
- More answers for the sake of having more answers

Here are some example questions:

- [How to align an object by one or two edges to xyz axes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6369/how-to-align-an-object-by-one-or-two-edges-to-xyz-axes/6376#6376)
- [Abstract Wave with Particle System](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7434/abstract-wave-with-particle-system/7436#7436)
- [How to stretch a mesh object over another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7194/how-to-stretch-a-mesh-object-over-another/7195#7195)
- [Cleanly Combine Two Landscapes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7457/1476)
- [How can I animate the camera in a perfect circular rotation around a fixed position?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3477/1476)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, each answer should contain one solution.  As a user, if I see several answers to a question I'm more inclined to think there's some interesting discussion going on that might be worth my time.  A question with a single right answer probably is very specific, and not generally applicable. A question with lots of answers will be more interesting.
It will also encourage better answers.  There's no reason for a single user to make more than one answer to a question, and if there's only one solution in that post they will choose what they feel is the best solution, rather than spewing off all possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

We could go through all posts looking for pages that meet the criteria of this topic and build each them into something that matches the expectations of people who search for this.

In essence, these pages could be the prototypes for tutorials and documentation that capture the the big picture by showing many uses from several different perspectives.  Often people find something useful that is unintended by the original software designers.  In this case the original tool turns out to have many more uses than originally expected because an artist made a mistake or was thinking *outside the box*.

To look at this another way, a page that fits this criteria would be complete and accurate supplementary material for the official docs on the BF site.

They could actually replace the official docs or be appended to them.

Out of all the conversations that I've had with BF devs and from all the times I've seen various BF devs interact with artists, I've gotten the impression that they are very moderate and reasonable people as a whole.  I think they would love it if this site became a refinement to the official documentation.  I'm sure if they felt otherwise they would never bother to show up here at all.

Comment: How to align an object by one or two edges to xyz axes?<-very ambiguous.  He uses several keywords that bridge many diverse topics.  He sounds like he is looking for a way to correct a key-stoke.  Or maybe he wants to adjust a keystroke with another and then he is asking about the physics engine.

Comment: To me, at first it seemed that he wants to constrain the transformation to one axis, well that's simple.  
Then he mentions far-reaching possible solutions and now I would have no idea what to write.  He made a mistake that caused confusion. This happens to everyone from time to time but can muddy the discussion.
The info on that page is valuable but needs to be made coherent.    This page could instead be replaced with a new page that fits the specifications for official BF docs which can now have an editing and rating system that is primarily based of the opinions of the BF Dev team.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes questions have answers that include dealing with aspects that the OP might not be aware of. In an attempt to be thorough why limit yourself to giving just one solution -- if someone has time to answer, let them do so in several ways. It will benefit someone somewhere down the line.

Precise questions tend to get few solutions, maybe because the OP restricts the elements that play in the scenario.

> Individual method have their own votes, it becomes very clear which is best

"best" may be subjective